# Getting the correct GMT format using DateFormat Object

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, gmt

If i have a `File` object how can i get the `lastModified()` date of this file in this GMT format: `Mon, 23 Jun 2011 17:40:23 GMT`.

For example, when i call the java method `lastModified()` on a file and use a DateFormat object to `getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.Long, DateFormat.Long)` and also set the `TimeZone` to GMT, the file date displays in different format:

```
File fileE = new File("/Some/Path");
Date fileDate = new Date (fileE.lastModified());
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.Long, DateFormat.Long);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("file date " + dateFormat.format(fileDate));
```

This prints in this format:

```
January 26, 2012 7:11:46 PM GMT
```

I feel like i am close to getting it in the format above and i am only missing the day. Do i have to use instead the `SimpleDateFormat` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SimpleDateFormat` with the pattern as follows:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
```

Update:

```
Date d1 = new Date(file1.lastModified());
Date d2 = new Date(file2.lastModified());
```

You can compare them as follows:

```
d1.compareTo(d2);
d1.before(d2);
d1.after(d2);
```

Why do you want to compare them at seconds granularity?

If you want to get the difference in seconds:

```
int diffInSeconds = (int) (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Comment: This format is great and prints my date object the way i want it to. Is it possible to get Date Objects that are in this format for comparison?

Comment: To print (display) you use it to format the Date object and if you have two different dates (string) that are in this format then parse and compare (using Date.compareTo(), Date.before(), or Date.after())

Comment: Make sure to use Locale.US on your SimpleDateFormat

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the DateFormat static instances will be locale specific.  If you want a specific format, you should use SimpleDateFormat with the appropriate format pattern.

If you want to compare 2 file modified times to the second granularity, then just divide them both by 1000, e.g.:

```
long t1InSeconds = f1.lastModified() / 1000L;
long t2InSeconds = f2.lastModified() / 1000L;

// which one is sooner
if(t1InSeconds < t2InSeconds) {
  // f1 is older ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried using the simpleDateFormat in many ways to get the above format. Is it possible to get a java date object in the format above? To clarify, I'm sure there is a format that i can use to print the date but what if i want to compare two dates to the second granularity and they need to be in the format i stated above. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Date objects don't have a format, they are just a millisecond value in UTC time.