# NSDate, Can't get proper date format

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is the timestamp I am trying to get my app to read: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 16:06:42 GMT

This is the closest I have, but haven't had any success:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z"];
```

EDIT: My current format prints-to/reads: Tue, 02 M02 2016 11:36:57 GMT-5

is there anything I'm missing?

Final Edit:

I should have just posted all my code...

```
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```

This was messing things up for me.

Comment: If you are looking for GMT, it has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024274/getting-the-correct-gmt-format-using-dateformat-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use your date format and convert it to a nsdate and back to a string. It should work with the format string you used.

```
let time = "Thu, 03 Mar 2016 16:06:42 GMT"
let dateformat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = dateformat
dateformatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

var date = dateformatter.dateFromString(time)

var newTime = dateformatter.stringFromDate(date!)
// newTime = "Thu, 03 Mar 2016 16:06:42 GMT"
```

Edit: I changed the dateformat to use lowercase `y`s for the year as suggested by Devster101. This is the correct format according to [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) spezification which is used since [iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Comment: Which locale are you on?

Comment: That is the problem. System locale is not for printing.

Comment: Use currentLocale instead

Comment: In addition to that you should use a dateformat like Devster101 suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your year is incorrect. Change your dateformat to

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
```

See documentation [on formatter dates here](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: So are you still having the same issue?

Comment: changing the year wont affect anything

Comment: Did you try it? YYYY and yyyy mean different things in date formats. yyyy is the one you want